# Inconsistent SQL query times with ODBC

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

Before anyone starts, I know that ODBC isn't the best way of doing things, but I'm constrained by previous versions of my company's software.
I've noticed some pretty drastic inconsistencies in query speed, and I'm trying to figure out what's going on, to see if there's anything I can do to improve it.  For example:

```
var strConnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=ODBC_DATA_MDB";
var db = new ActiveXObject("adodb.Connection");
var cmd = new ActiveXObject("adodb.Command");
db.Open(strConnect); 
var strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblHeatsetDay SELECT * FROM tblHeatsetRecord WHERE DateTime >= {fn CURDATE()};";
cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
cmd.ActiveConnection = db;
cmd.Execute();
```

Sometimes this runs in a split second, and sometimes it takes anywhere up to 15 seconds or so.  The file my ODBC connection is referencing is a local .mdb, and I know that there's nothing else opening it, altering it, or querying it in any way.

Is there anything about ODBC that's making it do this?  Anything I can do to improve the consistency?  Or at the very least, is there a way to find out exactly what's going on when it takes so long?

Comment: Microsoft has switched back to ODBC, OleDB is deprecated ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967418.aspx)

Comment: I understand you are constrained but is it possible to test using DAO + linked tables just to double check that its not potentially something else going on with your local hardware?  Probably pointless test but might give insight

Comment: I'm simply asking for all-purpose knowledge, but how many times have you seen this inconsistency? What are the differences (programs running, computer checking for updates, updates downloading in the background) between the times where it has lagged versus executed quickly? There are many things to consider here.

Comment: @OverMind, I've seen it on every computer I've run the program on (5 or 6 different ones so far) each with different hardware and versions of windows (some with 7, and some still with XP).  I've run it on 32bit systems and 64bit systems, I've run it on a LAN and completely disconnected from any network.  This made me think it was something in the code (since that's just about the only thing left in common), but after commenting out everything but the above snippet (which is about as simplistic as I can make it) I'm still seeing problems.

Comment: It's definitely related to ODBC; when I use a Microsoft Jet OLEDB connection string, it's lightning-fast every time.  But I've had my hand smacked for this in the past; they want to keep everything ODBC.  Is there some parameter I could be using in the connection string that would help out here?  Some way of configuring the ODBC link differently?

Comment: I'm confused. The code looks like C#, but you are using COM (ADODB.Connection) instead of `System.Data.Odbc`. Your connection string specifies a `Provider=` which suggests OLEDB (and MSDASQL.1 looks like SQL Server, not Access) but your `Data Source=` looks like an ODBC DSN. Perhaps the computers in question are getting as confused as I am. :)

Comment: @GordThompson It's Javascript; believe it or not, I have to run everything inside some sort of proprietary web browser, so I'm forced to rely on ActiveX components *everywhere.*

Comment: Interesting. One thing I'd be inclined to try would be to just use `DSN=ODBC_DATA_MDB;` as the connection string. That other stuff might simply be ignored, but it's probably not helping anything.

Answer (score 0):

In ODBC that should just resolve to either a single call to SQLExecDirect or two calls to SQLPrepare and SQLExecute. If you program is repeatedly doing this then it makes more sense to SQLPrepare once and SQLExecute each time you want to execute the SQL - I cannot tell you how to do this in javascript. It depends how you javascript library is written to use ODBC but at most I'd expect:

```
SQLPrepare(the sql)
SQLExecute
SQLNumResultCols
SQLRowCount
```

I cannot believe this is responsible for the inconsistency and in any case you are not even returning any rows. What is more likely is that your select statement is returning differing numbers of rows each time you call it. Other than that whether you are in a transaction or using AutoCommit could make some difference but it would not on its own explain what you are seeing.